# What are Issues with Using Two Crash Reporters in Your App?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics

I am currently using Crashlytics in my app and it's working well. However, we are thinking of using NewRelic on the backend to better be able to pinpoint issues in our platform. The NewRelic mobile library has a crash reporter built into it as well (that can be opted out of).

I am assuming you don't want to use two crash reporters considering one will trump the other, however, I haven't seen any information on this anywhere and would just like to confirm.

Additionally if you could explain why along with the answer that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one signal handler installed. The last one that registers "wins".